# Telegraf not working with sysstat options like `-d` or `-n ALL`?

Tags: monitoring, telegraf

I am attempting to setup [Telegraf](https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf) on a [Proxmox](https://www.proxmox.com/) (Debian-based distro) to send metrics to [InfluxDB](https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb). However, it seems to be complaining about sysstat syntax.

I am using the [sysstat plugin in Telegraf](https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf/tree/master/plugins/inputs/sysstat).

Per the configuration file, I have a section like this

```
#   ## sysstat version.
#   [inputs.sysstat.options]
#     -C = "cpu"
#     -B = "paging"
#     -b = "io"
#     -d = "disk"             # requires DISK activity
     "-n ALL" = "network"
#     "-P ALL" = "per_cpu"
#     -q = "queue"
#     -R = "mem"
     -r = "mem_util"
#     -S = "swap_util"
#     -u = "cpu_util"
#     -v = "inode"
#     -W = "swap"
#     -w = "task"
#   #  -H = "hugepages"        # only available for newer linux distributions
#   #  "-I ALL" = "interrupts" # requires INT activity
```

However, it appears to be erroring out on these options:

```
root@syd1:/var/run/ceph# telegraf --test
2019-03-15T07:56:35Z I! Starting Telegraf 1.10.0
2019-03-15T07:56:35Z I! Using config file: /etc/telegraf/telegraf.conf
2019-03-15T07:56:35Z E! [telegraf] Error running agent: Error parsing /etc/telegraf/telegraf.conf, line 3845: field corresponding to `-n ALL' is not defined in `*sysstat.Sysstat'
```

Yet if I run `sysstat -h`, I see:

```
root@syd1:/var/run/ceph# sar -h
Usage: sar [ options ] [ <interval> [ <count> ] ]
Main options and reports:
        -B      Paging statistics
        -b      I/O and transfer rate statistics
        -d      Block devices statistics
        -F [ MOUNT ]
                Filesystems statistics
        -H      Hugepages utilization statistics
        -I { <int> | SUM | ALL | XALL }
                Interrupts statistics
        -m { <keyword> [,...] | ALL }
                Power management statistics
                Keywords are:
                CPU     CPU instantaneous clock frequency
                FAN     Fans speed
                FREQ    CPU average clock frequency
                IN      Voltage inputs
                TEMP    Devices temperature
                USB     USB devices plugged into the system
        -n { <keyword> [,...] | ALL }
                Network statistics
                Keywords are:
                DEV     Network interfaces
                EDEV    Network interfaces (errors)
                NFS     NFS client
                NFSD    NFS server
                SOCK    Sockets (v4)
                IP      IP traffic      (v4)
                EIP     IP traffic      (v4) (errors)
                ICMP    ICMP traffic    (v4)
                EICMP   ICMP traffic    (v4) (errors)
                TCP     TCP traffic     (v4)
                ETCP    TCP traffic     (v4) (errors)
                UDP     UDP traffic     (v4)
                SOCK6   Sockets (v6)
                IP6     IP traffic      (v6)
                EIP6    IP traffic      (v6) (errors)
                ICMP6   ICMP traffic    (v6)
                EICMP6  ICMP traffic    (v6) (errors)
                UDP6    UDP traffic     (v6)
                FC      Fibre channel HBAs
        -q      Queue length and load average statistics
        -R      Memory statistics
        -r [ ALL ]
                Memory utilization statistics
        -S      Swap space utilization statistics
        -u [ ALL ]
                CPU utilization statistics
        -v      Kernel tables statistics
        -W      Swapping statistics
        -w      Task creation and system switching statistics
        -y      TTY devices statistics
```

So things like `-d` or `-n ALL` **are** available.

Any idea what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

Whoops, this was actually a syntax error in my config file. Specifically, I needed to uncomment the line:

[inputs.sysstat.options]

which comes just before the

```
#     -C = "cpu"
#     -B = "paging"
#     -b = "io"
     -d = "disk"             # requires DISK activity
     "-n ALL" = "network"
#     "-P ALL" = "per_cpu"
#     -q = "queue"
#     -R = "mem"
     -r = "mem_util"
#     -S = "swap_util"
#     -u = "cpu_util"
#     -v = "inode"
#     -W = "swap"
#     -w = "task"
#   #  -H = "hugepages"        # only available for newer linux distributions
#   #  "-I ALL" = "interrupts" # requires INT activity
```

Without it, it didn't parse the above lines correctly.